# Jquery prevent default doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, preventdefault

I have tried by following code to prevent default of form submitting, but it doesn't work. What is problem to that.

```
<div class="section-register">
    <form id="registerform" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="http://localhost/yify2/wp-login.php?action=register" name="registerform">
        <input id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" type="submit" value="Register" name="wp-submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

My script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".section-register").find("#registerform").submit(function(event){
        if(whatever) { 
            event.preventDefault();  
        }  
      });
   });
</script>
```

I also tried by following code :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#registerform").submit( function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are your form loaded via AJAX?

Comment: Second script is working on fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/qyb3oafp/

Comment: Yeah, I have loaded form jquery axaj.

Comment: what is the "whatever" variable?

Comment: @JonasGrumann I guess OP removed all of the if "junk" to focus on the main problem

Comment: but i prefer to use second script. but it doesn't word. Plz, help on second script.

Comment: Thanks for try for me. I have got the answer form "dev-null".  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your form is loaded via an AJAX request you will need to bind the event after the form is added to the DOM, or bind it on a static node:

**Delegated event binding**:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) { // Short for jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the event to a static node (here I use document). 
    //   The closer to the dynamic node the better.
    // From your code it looks like you might be able to use  
    //   $('.section-register') as the static node.
    $(document).on('submit', '#registerform', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Sobujalice Note that it would be a good idea to change `$(document)` to a closer static node, eg `$('.section-register')`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("form[name=registerform]").submit( function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why should this do a difference?

Comment: Different selector for form

Comment: Yes i can see the difference, but what should it help changing the selector?